# How can i pause and resume progress bar in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Hi i am using a progressbar and i need to pause it and resume it. This is my code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressbar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                    }
                });
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1790741/

Comment: You do not pause or resume the progress bar. You set the progress by the setProgress(int) method. You pause or resume the action that is updating the progress bar. In your case you could create a variable and check this before progressbar.setProgress(); When you want to pause the bar you can set this variable to false.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code where I have used a horizontal progress bar

```
public class currentsong extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img_play, shuffle, repeat, song_image;
boolean state_playbutton, state_shuffle, state_repeat;
TextView name_of_song, name_of_artist;
```

1) Declare these variables as shown below:-

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
boolean temp=true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_currentsong);


    img_play = findViewById(R.id.play);
    shuffle = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
    repeat = findViewById(R.id.repeat);
    song_image = findViewById(R.id.song_image);
    name_of_song = findViewById(R.id.name_of_song);
    name_of_artist = findViewById(R.id.name_of_artist);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    state_playbutton = true;
    state_shuffle = true;
    state_repeat = true;
```

2)As my activity starts, my thread should run so i used thread.start();

```
    thread.start();

    img_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(state_playbutton)
            {
                img_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                state_playbutton = false;
```

3)I used this variable so that while loop will not run in thread defined below i.e. thread execution will pause

```
                temp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                img_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                state_playbutton = true;
```

4)Now to resume thread execution, set temp = true and I used thread.start() so thread will resume where it left

```
                temp = true;
                thread.start();
            }

        }
    });


}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 300 && temp) {
            // Update the progress status
            progressStatus += 1;

            // Try to sleep the thread for 100 milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update the progress bar
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}